# Unary operator '++' used. Lint Error in a while loop

Tags: javascript

I made a function that sums the average of an array, but I'm having problems with lint, it talks about i++, I've tried [i += 1]; but it breaks my code.

```
function average(myArray) {
  let i = 0;
   let summ = 0;
   if (myArray.length === 0) return undefined;
   
    let ArrayVz = myArray.length;
  while (i < ArrayVz) {
    summ += myArray[i += 1];
    if (typeof summ === 'string') return undefined;
  }
  return Math.round(summ / ArrayVz);
}
```

Comment: What you are trying with this summ += myArray[i += 1] ?

Comment: linters just define a code style, and (probably the default) code style defined by your linter just doesn't want you to use `i++` inside square brackets. You can either change the rule or expand the instructions to two lines

Comment: Why isn't this a `for` loop to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

`i++` and `i += 1` give different results … which is why your linter is complaining about using `i++` in the first place. It makes for confusing code.

You appear to want to take the value of `i` and **then** add one to it for the next loop.

`i++` will so that, but `i += 1` adds one **before** taking the *new* value.

---

Split your code out into separate statements to make it clearer (the order is explicit) and easier to maintain.

```
summ += myArray[i];
i += 1;
```

---

It would be more idiomatic to write it as a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop though.

Comment: Showww!! it worked I'm very grateful, I'm studying programming recently, I'll pay more attention now to make the code clearer!!!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed, your not counting i up. I would use a for loop like this

```
function average(myArray) {
  let i = 0;
   let summ = 0;
   if (myArray.length === 0) return undefined;
   
    let ArrayVz = myArray.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < ArrayVz.length; i++) {
    summ += myArray[i];
    if (typeof summ === 'string') return undefined;
  }
  return Math.round(summ / ArrayVz);
}
```

Comment: Yes he's doing that. `myArray[i++]` is taking care of increasing the `i` variable

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
function average(myArray) {
          let i = 0;
           let summ = 0;
           if (myArray.length === 0) return undefined;
           
            let ArrayVz = myArray.length;
          for (let i = 0; i < ArrayVz.length; i++) {
            summ += myArray[++i];
            if (typeof summ === 'string') return undefined;
          }
          return Math.round(summ / ArrayVz);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just disable the lint error for next line for ++ and use it